# " ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension " in 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install Sass. Went through this guide to install Ruby which [Sass website](http://sass-lang.com/install) told is a pre-requisite

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04

Looks like it went well

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Now I am stuck at this point. I am not sure how to proceed further. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ sudo gem install sass
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171122-3627-1olbmft.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

What should I do now ? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

The above command fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing libffi-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it an unstable package ( dev ) ? Just curious.

Comment: I got this   $ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
[sudo] password for dna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**libffi-dev is already the newest version (3.2.1-4).**
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.